# PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo

Tags: php, laravel, docker, mariadb

I am trying to run the foowing command in my laravel project with docker:

```
php artisan migrate
```

But it is throwing me this error:

PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

It seems it is not able to connect to the database. Although it's running properly. I checked that already.

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    links:
      - mariadb:mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    ports:
      - "13306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel_app
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Can you verify the .env file even gets added to the container? Access the shell via `exec` and verify you can cat the contents. Want to make sure there's not a .dockerignore line keeping it from being added to the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you run the `php artisan migrate` command outside the container? Running the laravel artisan command from host won't work. You should run it inside the container. If you are using `docker-compose`, try this this command to run command inside container:

```
docker exec -it <container name> /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan migrate

or 

docker-compose exec <container name> /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan migrate
```

If you already set your workdir to `/var/www/html` in your `Dockerfile`, you can remove the `/var/www/html` from the command. Hope it helps.

Comment: That hint solved it! I had to adjust the command a bit for my case. Thanks a lot!